# Forth stack comments with return stack

Tags: forth

What should the stack comments look like when the return stack comes into play?

```
: FOO  ( d2 d1 tos -- sum flag ) 
   ... ;
```

This word expects 5 cells and returns 2 cells, but what goes between the parentheses when the return stack is used?  e.g. how would the stack comment look for this:

```
: BAZ  ( d2 d1 tos -- d )
   BASE @ >R >R   ( d2 d1 )
   2SWAP D-   ( d ) 
   R> DUP
   R@ BAR
   R> BONK ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return stack effect is noted separately and prefixed with `R:`.

See [dpANS Forth 2.2.2](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans2.htm#2.2.2).  As an example, [the description of `>R`](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.0580): "*Execution: ( x -- ) ( R:  -- x )*"